# Text In Sidebar Won't Hide After Collapsing Sidebar

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a sidebar shrink affect when you collapse the sidebar using custom CSS, jQuery, and Bootstrap. My custom CSS and jQuery are handling the shrink affect and Bootstrap is used just for styling. For some reason, some of the elements in the sidebar won't go away or hide after the shrink collapse. I've given a strip down example in my code below. And some images as examples.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Images (before and after):

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        /* Styling when the Sidebar is open to apply the 'shrink' effect. */
        .not-bs-sidebar {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
            -o-transition: all 0.8s;
            transition: all 0.8s;
        }

        /* Styling to make the Main area fill the page when the Sidebar is collapsed. */
        .not-bs-main {
            flex: 1;
        }

        /* Styling to collapse the Sidebar. */
        .not-bs-sidebar.active {
            width: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 bg-primary not-bs-sidebar" id="sidebar" style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <h1>WTF! Why won't this hide?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 not-bs-main" id="main">
            <div class="row not-bs-header bg-dark">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="ButtonCollapse">
                            <i class="bi bi-justify"></i>
                        </button>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row not-bs-body">
                <div class="col" style="height: 400px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ButtonCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        })
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating this:

```
.not-bs-sidebar {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

to this:

```
.not-bs-sidebar {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was easy. That did it. Thanks!